# how to check if a 2D array of type any object contains something in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

I have a 2D array declared as `var cellitemcontent:[[AnyObject]] = []`

I store a string and bool value in it ( [apple, false; banana, false; egg, true])

When I try to see if cellitemcontent contains any false values I do:

```c
if cellitemcontent[0][1] as Bool == false {} //fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer
```

Or if I try:

```c
if contains((cellitemcontent[0][1] as Bool), false) {} //Type 'Bool' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

P.S: The reason I have it as AnyObject instead of a tuple is because I save this to NSUserDefaults and I was told that you can't save a touple in defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also `map` `cellItemContents` to an array of just the `Bool` values - the indexes of the new array would match the indexes of the original array:

```
let bools = cellItemContents.map { $0[1] as Bool }
```

Taking your original array of `[[apple, false], [banana, false], [egg, true]]`, you'd get a new array, `[false, false, true]`, that you could do whatever you want with:

```
println(contains(bools, false))  // prints "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never compare a Bool type to true. It is redundant. You can simply do:

```
if (cellitemcontent[0][1] as Bool) {
    // your code
}
```

or if you would like to check if it is false just add an exclamation mark in front of it:

```
if !(cellitemcontent[0][1] as Bool) {
    // your code
}
```

//

```
var cellitemcontent:[[AnyObject]] = []

cellitemcontent.append(["apple", false])
cellitemcontent.append(["banana", false])
cellitemcontent.append(["egg", true])

for index in 0..<cellitemcontent.count {
    if !(cellitemcontent[index][1] as Bool) {
        println("is false")   // (2 times)
    } else {
        println("is true")    // (1 time)
    }
}
```

Comment: hm, but how would I go through the entire list instead of individual values [?][1] ? should I do a for loop?

Comment: Just put it inside a simple loop and use an index

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need for a 2D array, you might have an easier time using a dictionary:

```
let myDict = ["apple": false, "banana": false, "egg": true]

if myDict["apple"]! {
    println("The food is an apple.")
} else {
    println("The food is not an apple.") // Prints
}

if myDict["banana"]! {
    println("The food is an apple.")
} else {
    println("The food is not an apple.") // Prints
}

if myDict["egg"]! {
    println("The food is an apple.") // Prints
} else {
    println("The food is not an apple.")
}
```

In response to your question in another comment, iterate like this:

```
for (food, value) in myDict {

    println("The \(food) is \(value)")
}
```

Comment: The dictionary idea is a great idea, but don't use the `!`. The code will blow up the instant you try to access a value that isn't in the dictionary - i.e., `if myDict["pear"]!`...kaboom.

Comment: I can't use a dictionary because this is more like a todo list and I constantly delete and insert new values and move them around and I need the indexPath etc.

Comment: I believe that Swift 1.2 returns optional values, so the "if let" pattern (which would be better anyway) would be the only other option. (I haven't been able to find documentation to confirm this yet.)